# EventSourcing+CQRS validations

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

When using EventSourcing and CQRS you usually have eventual consistency in your read models. Let's say we have a `Customer` entity which is eventsourced and this entity has a social security number property. This number must be unique, so when creating a new `Customer` we have to check if that number is not already used.

What is the usual approach to do that sort of validation? I can see three options:

1. Load the whole bunch of events for all `Customer` entities, rehydrate all of them, then verify is none is using the number again.
2. Query the read model, but everything I read about ES+CQRS explicitly says we should not do that because of eventual consistency.
3. Have a separate table for those numbers only (preferably in the same database of the events, so we can save the events and the numbers in the same transaction, assuming it is a relational database).

Option 3 seems to be the best option if we're using relational databases, because if everything happens within the same transaction, we don't suffer from eventual consistency.

I can see the same happening for queries like 'get all customers with age above 30'. I cannot see different options than rebuilding the whole streams to query them, or querying the read models.

Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having a dependence on a relational DB, the purer CQRS/ES approach I can think of would be to have the tracking of the SS# -> customer mapping (since it's likely going to be immutable (changing an SS# is possible but rare enough that you may well be able to defer incorporating that until a lot later)) in an event-sourced entity that only tracks that: the customer entity gets created as a projection of that mapping entity emitting an event associating the SS# to a prospective customer.

For example:

- `AssociateSocialSecurityWithCustomer("012-34-5678", desiredCustId, name)` => ssnum-to-customer entity
- if this is the first event seen by that entity, a `SocialSecurityNumberAssociatedWith(desiredCustId, name)` event is emitted
- consumer of that event stream translates that into a genesis command for customer entity

If there are multiple validations like this, you can resort to a saga which is sending commands to multiple entities (e.g. to handle the case where customer already has an SS#) and rolling back on failures.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with 3) too:

- You can have a view that selects from the log for the `ClientRegistered` event, take the unique ID (SSN?), and extract it from the event payload (most databases allow JSON querying). May not work well if the payload of the event is encrypted but should work with field-level encryption.
- Your `RegisterClientHandler` can also verify from a separate table and, if the SSN does not exist, a) write to the IDs table, b) write to the log, and c) compensate a) if the write to the log fails for any reason.